# How to create and access multiple children of the root node in Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to access the books field in the database. I have created a fragment with a recyclerview that displays the books. What I needed in the app is that each user should be able to request only one book. So I created another node directly under the root node as "users", but after adding the "users" node the recyclerview is not working properly. This is how the database looks after adding "users". [Database Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0utiy.png)

Here is the Before Recyclerview: 
[Before Adding users field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKcWS.png)

Here is the After RecyclerView:
[After Adding users field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rku8e.png)

Here is the exported json code from firebase database.`

```
{
  "books" : {
    "BOOK 1 BY AUTHOR 1": {
      "author" : "Author 1",
      "category" : "CLASSICAL",
      "description" : "",
      "image" : "NO_IMAGE",
      "requested" : "NO",
      "requester" : "NO_ONE",
      "title" : "Book 1"
    },
    "BOOK 2 BY AUTHOR 2" : {
      "author" : "Author 2",
      "category" : "SPIRITUALITY",
      "description" : "",
      "image" : "NO_IMAGE",
      "requested" : "NO",
      "requester" : "NO_ONE",
      "title" : "Book 2"
    },
    "BOOK 3  BY AUTHOR 3" : {
      "author" : "author 3",
      "category" : "ADVENTURE",
      "description" : "",
      "image" : "NO_IMAGE",
      "requested" : "NO",
      "requester" : "NO_ONE",
      "title" : "book 3 "
    }
  },
  "user" : {
    "User1" : {
      "requestedBook" : "no"
    },
    "User2" : {
      "requestedBook" : "yes"
    }
  }
}
```

`This is the fragment code.

```
    package club.bms.keshav.readersreserve.fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import club.bms.keshav.readersreserve.NewBookAttributes;
import club.bms.keshav.readersreserve.R;
import club.bms.keshav.readersreserve.dataHelper.Book;
import club.bms.keshav.readersreserve.dataHelper.BooksAdapter;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{
    private static final String TAG = "HomeFragment";
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
    BooksAdapter adapter;
    private ChildEventListener childEventListener;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    public HomeFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_recyclerview_declaration, container, false);
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: background color set");
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_home_fragment);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        final Context context = view.getContext();
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.add_book_fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(context, NewBookAttributes.class));
            }
        });


        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(view.getContext(), 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: recyclerview set without adapter");
         databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
         databaseReference.keepSynced(true);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: database ref created");
        childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: ");
                getAllBooks(dataSnapshot, context);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onChildChanged: ");
                getAllBooks(dataSnapshot, context);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                taskDeletion(dataSnapshot, context);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
            databaseReference.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: added listener");
         return view;
    }


    private void taskDeletion(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, Context context) {

        for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            Book book = snapshot.getValue(Book.class);
            Book tempBook = new Book();
            tempBook.setAuthor(book.getAuthor());
            tempBook.setTitle(book.getTitle());
            tempBook.setDescription(book.getDescription());
            for(int i=0;i<bookList.size();i++)
            {
                Book b = bookList.get(i);
                if(b.getAuthor().equals(tempBook.getAuthor()) && b.getTitle().equals(tempBook.getTitle()))
                {
                    bookList.remove(i);
                }
            }
        }
        adapter = new BooksAdapter(context, bookList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.d(TAG, "taskDeletion: adapter set");

    }

    private  void getAllBooks(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, Context context) {

       bookList.clear();
        Book book;
        for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            book = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Book.class);
            bookList.add(book);
        }
        adapter = new BooksAdapter(context, bookList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.d(TAG, "getAllBooks: adapter set");
        }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        databaseReference.removeEventListener(childEventListener);
        Log.d(TAG, "onDetach: removed listener");
    }
}
```

When I add the "users" node programmatically, the card view becomes empty, and on clicking the card view, it gives NullPointerException.

Here is the code for the RecyclerView Adapter

```
    package club.bms.keshav.readersreserve.dataHelper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import java.util.List;

import club.bms.keshav.readersreserve.ConstantFields;
import club.bms.keshav.readersreserve.GlideApp;
import club.bms.keshav.readersreserve.R;
import club.bms.keshav.readersreserve.Single_Book_Activity;

class   RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnLongClickListener, View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView mAuthor, mTitle, mCategory;
    public ImageView mBookImage;
    //public TextView btn, mauthor;

    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mAuthor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textV_book_author);
        mTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textV_book_title);
        mBookImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_for_book);
        mCategory = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textV_book_category);
        //        mStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textV_book_status);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);

    }

    public void setmBookImage(String path, final Context context)
    {
        if(path == null || path.equals(ConstantFields.NO_IMAGE))
        {
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(R.drawable.default_book_cover)
                    .into(mBookImage);
        }
        else{
            StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("images/" + path + "/" + path + " cover");

            GlideApp.with(MyApp.getAppContext())
                    .load(storageReference)
                    .apply(new RequestOptions()
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.rolling_placeholder)
                            .error(R.drawable.default_book_cover)
                    )
                    .into(mBookImage);
        }

    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition(), false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition(), true);
        return true;
    }
}


public class BooksAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Book> bookList;
    private Book book;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener = new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClicked) {
            if (isLongClicked) {

//                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
//                builder.setMessage("DELETE");
//                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
//                dialog.show();

                //DO SOMETHING
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Single_Book_Activity.class);
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                book = bookList.get(position);
                args.putSerializable("bookObject", book);
                intent.putExtras(args);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };

    public BooksAdapter(Context mContext, List<Book> bookList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.bookList = bookList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.book_list_row, parent, false);
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int i) {
        book = bookList.get(i);
        holder.mAuthor.setText(book.getAuthor());
        holder.mTitle.setText(book.getTitle());
        holder.mCategory.setText(book.getCategory());
        holder.setmBookImage(book.getImage(), mContext);
        holder.setItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bookList.size();
    }

}
```

Is there any other way using which, I can apply the one user, one book rule?

On changing the code to

```
      databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(ConstantFields.CHILD_BOOK);
         bookRef = databaseReference.child(ConstantFields.CHILD_BOOK);
bookRef.addChildEventListener(...);
```

I can add the books successfully to the desired position in the database(I have no idea how), but OnChildAdded() or onChildChanged() method does not get called, hence the progress bar keeps on displaying infinitely, and the books are not displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your database reference.

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference
```

this will check the whole of your database.

Your child event listener should check to database.child("books")

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference
dbBooks = db.child("books")
dbBooks.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener{
}
```

Comment: I changed the database reference to : databasereference = Firebasedatabase.getInstance.getReference.child("books");   On adding this line of code it gives DatabaseException Error. [StackTrace](https://imgur.com/OLQ1Zca)

Comment: Your stacktrace states the error can't convert string to Book class. Debug inside the get all books method.

Also Initialize your db reference without a child. 

And then when using your db look at using databaseReference.child("books") with the event listeners.

Comment: After i referenced the "books" node seperately, it solved the problem.DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference
dbBooks = db.child("books")
dbBooks.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener{
}

Answer (score 0):

I think JJ Swart's answer is right, problem here is your BookReference refererences to whole of your data instead of only your "books's data". Can you show us your Exception info to see what's really your error after you changes the reference to "books".